# SonarQube : " Project configuration file: NONE "

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I've configured everything to do a Sonar analysis on a Maven project. Everything is fine until I run `sonar-runner` :

```
     Max$ sonar-runner
     INFO: Scanner configuration file: /Users/Max/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/conf/sonar-runner.properties
     INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
     INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.5
     INFO: Java 1.7.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
     INFO: Mac OS X 10.10.3 x86_64
     INFO: User cache: /Users/Max/.sonar/cache
     INFO: Load global repositories
     INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=143ms
     INFO: Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
     INFO: User cache: /Users/Max/.sonar/cache
     INFO: Load plugins index
     INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=4ms
     INFO: Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis  is platform dependent)
     INFO: Process project properties
     INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
     INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     INFO: Total time: 1.631s
     INFO: Final Memory: 40M/194M
     INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
     ERROR: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
     ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class     org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor
     ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
     ERROR: 
     ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube  Scanner with the -e switch.
     ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

- I'm running `sonar-runner` inside my java project folder
- I have put and configured the `sonar-runner.properties` in my java project

  ```
  sonar.projectKey=SeleniumMaven:sonar
  sonar.projectName=SeleniumMaven
  sonar.projectVersion=1.0
  sonar.sources=src
  sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
  sonar.language=java
  ```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using Sonar Runner if you have a Maven project? Just use the Sonar Maven Plugin.

Comment: In my case it turned out I was calling the scanner from a wrong location. Don't forget the `dir` step if using Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I realized my file name was incorrect: instead of "sonar-project.properties" I had it as "sonar-project.properties.properties".

I would try and change your file name to "sonar-project.properties" and try ...

Comment: In my case the file name had special character


`mv sonar-project.properties̀ sonar-project.properties`

Comment: brilliant!....in my case i had named it sonar-projects.properties

Comment: Thank you!!, in my case, I had whitespace before the file name which was completely invisible when I saw your answer I was sure this isn’t the case until I realized the problem :O

Answer (score 6):

Try passing the values like this :

`sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectKey=..... -Dsonar.projectName=...`

if it works, it means the property file is somewhat ignored

If you look at the following message :

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /Users/Max/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
```

It seems like your project configuration file is indeed ignored

Comment: Well thanks, it's working ! Don't know why my property file is ignored !

Comment: Do you run the command from the project's root directory ? 

However, as stated by @Tunaki, you should use the sonar maven plugin if your project is maven based. 

This way you could attach the analysis to a maven phase etc..

Answer (score 6):

You need create a [configuration file](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Use) in the root directory of the project: **sonar-project.properties**

If a **sonar-project.properties** file cannot be created(or you won`t) in the root directory of the project, there are [several alternatives](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages#AdvancedSonarQubeScannerUsages-Alternativestosonar-project.properties):

- The properties can be specified directly through the command line. Ex:

  sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=myproject -Dsonar.sources=src1
- The property project.settings can be used to specify the path to the
  project configuration file (this option is incompatible with the
  project.home and sonar.projectBaseDir properties). Ex:

  sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=../myproject.properties

The root folder of the project to analyze can be set through the **sonar.projectBaseDir** property since SonarQube Scanner 2.4 (was previously project.home). This folder must contain a **sonar-project.properties** file if the **mandatory** properties (like **sonar.projectKey**) are not specified on the command line.

*[Additional analysis parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) can be defined in this project configuration file or through command-line parameters.*

Comment: Thank you,, my issue is resolved. It was copy and paste error. I have copied file from sonar scanner and put it directly in to my project root, not realizing that the names are different for both files. For project is is "-project" and not "-scanner"